# Install Scribus 1.5 On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, scribus

Can someone outline how to install Scribus on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7):

You just have to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install scribus-ng
```

in the terminal.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, thanks for the edit.  :)  Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

*To install the last stable version*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install scribus
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04

*To install the last dev version*

```
Add the repository 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 

Install Scribus 
sudo apt-get install scribus-trunk -y
```

Comment: installing the "scribus" package gave you the stable version at that time (1.4.x). the question is about getting the development version 1.5.x

Comment: You're right, my proposal lead to install the last stable version.  In the title the version is about the 1.5 but not in the question. "Can someone outline how to install Scribus on Ubuntu 16.04". Therefore, I am not sure at all, that the requester wanted to get the development version. Moreover, on my ubuntu, the ng version didn't install. I hope that my answer could have helped some people to use Scribus.