# How to generate QR Codes using LibreOffice in Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice

I want to generate QR codes in Ubuntu 22.04. How to do it using LibreOffice?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/959193/124466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LibreOffice to generate QR Codes.

Go to `Insert -> OLE Object -> QR and barcode`
[image]

Afterwards, you can paste text/url, and also set margin and error correction limit.

[image]

For more details, check out https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-GB/text/shared/guide/qrcode.html